# timeout on updating nvarchar(max) after converting datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes, query-timeout

I recently Upgraded to 2008 Enterprise and took the opportunity to change the biggest table in my db with the maintenance window.

ran the following to change my ntext field

```
ALTER TABLE acomEstabLocale_tbl ALTER COLUMN [description] nvarchar(MAX)
GO
update acomEstabLocale_tbl set [description] = [description]
```

when I ran the second statement i got the following

```
length of LOB data (77404) to be replicated exceeds the exceeds configured maximum
```

ok, so after a poke around I found the sp_configure and ran :-

```
EXEC sp_configure ‘max text repl size’, 100000
```

but now I receiving the following

```
nvarchar max Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I'm looking to temporarily extend this query timeout period, can the just be done using the remote query timeout setting on the server properties ? or is there a T-SQL statement for just this query

Comment: Why are you running a self-update like that to touch all the rows?

Comment: Also some other questions - did you upgrade (in-place, detach/attach, or backup/restore), or did you build a new version on the new server? (I'm fishing for potential collation changes.) Also did you set compat level on the new database, and did you update stats on this table before you ran the update?

Comment: no I tried to update the collation on the db with a test system as the server and database are different. but this caused issues so I mirrored the config on the new server for now as my window was very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the purpose is of your entire-table-update, but perhaps the timeout is because your query is causing:

- stats to be created
- triggers to be fired
- massive writes to the log (and potentially you are waiting on log file auto-grow - instant file initialization doesn't help you here)

If this table is replicated, the database is mirrored, or you've added CDC/Change Tracking then I think it is going to be much worse. If the table is participating in replication, [you should read this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

What is the update supposed to do? It's too late now for this case but in the future an alternative way to do this for other tables might be:

1. add a new column with the new data type
2. populate it *in batches* with values from the old column, and use transactions or checkpoints to minimize impact to the log (and subsequent features that use the log)
3. once done, rename or drop the old column, then rename the new column to the old name

Of course this still has to be done in a maintenance window. You don't want users contending for writes during 2.

Comment: Hi Aaron. Its a live site, so I setup log shipping to my new server after a full restore. I did the update to itself as was reading an article / blog by someone previously who said this was a strange necessary step to recover the space saved by the nvarchar(max).   I did this as one of my first upgrade tests before updating all stats as obviously wanted to test website functionality.    My db is running in 2005 compatability for 1 week and then I intend to upgrade to 2008, thanks

Comment: And did you actually observe that space was wasted? I would worry about this when you're doing normal table maintenance anyway, not introduce this hacky kludge as part of your change.

Comment: I noticed in a test system that the space had not been reclaimed,  it did reclaim the space when the log had caught up after running the statement.  Well I received the timeout so I still need to run the statement again... I take it your suggesting this isn't the preferred method :)   can you let me know what would be the most lightweight / preferential, many thanks. Will updating all stats or changing the compatibility version resolve this anyway ?   would you update the new column in a where claus?  my main reason to do this was to stop this unecessary LOB being replicated to 3 subscribers

Comment: How is updating it to the same value going to prevent it from being replicated to 3 subscribers?

Comment: sorry, the datatype will still replicate but as a nvarchar(max) instead of the next(blob) be in row if it can fit it in (which is nearly always can).

Comment: I see, you're talking about the main reason to perform the `ALTER` - I was questioning the value of performing the `UPDATE` not the `ALTER`. Still seems like a dirty way to have that effect, even if it does work. I've been meaning to do some tests around this (and even have a blog post stub on my queue).